# How can i get Angular model as single Object?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am implementing an application using angular. I have layout like following json.

```
{
  "type" : "text",
  "subtype" : "string",
  "name" : "Test"
  "value": "Sample Value"
},
{
  "type" : "radio",
  "subtype" : "array",
  "name" : "radioTest"
  "value": ['test','test2','test3']
},
{
  "type" : "checkbox",
  "subtype" : "arrayOfObject",
  "name" : "checkBoxTest"
  "value": [{key : 'test',value:'value'},{key : 'test',value:'value1'},{key : 'test',value:'value3'}]
},
```

This is just sample json. But real time json is different. It may have any number of components, and any kind of types.
Here based on "type" and "sub type" property, i will create Own Component using Directive. 
My Requirement are : 
1. how to make mapping to these property dynamically.
2. i need to get the model as single object.
   for eg: mapData= {"checkBoxTest":"test","Test":"Sample Value"}
3. How manage Scope.

Can any one help on these.

Comment: Could you make a plunker of what you have already tried?

Comment: ...or even just show that you tried anything

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can't write a function that change dinamically the field to reache in the json file, not in the way you intend to, but you can make a for statement with an if inside that return only the field you need for example

```
var key=[]
var myarray=[]
for(s=0;s<data.value.length;s++){
    key.push(ata.value[s])
}
for(c=0;c<data.length;c++){
    if(data.value.length==0){
       myarray.push({
            type:data[c].type,
            subtype:data[c].subtype,
            value:data[c].value
       }
    else{
            type:data.type,
            subtype:data.subtype,
            value:key
    }
```

i don't know if it can solve your specific problem but it's a good way to do that